# NVIDIA Installer Failed - How to upgrade from CUDA 5.0 to CUDA 5.5?

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, cuda

I have CUDA 5.0 and need to upgrade to CUDA 5.5. When I run the CUDA 5.5 Installer (default settings), it fails during installation of the CUDA Toolkit, and displays a dialog box with the following message:

"NVIDIA Installer Failed."

If I close the installer and try again, I get a different error:

"NVIDIA Installer Cannot Continue: Required Files Are Missing."

If I reboot and try again, I get the first message once again.

Is there a driver for 5.0 I need to uninstall for 5.5 to install? Any help is appreciated.

I'm using Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: This installer should have a log.  can you post the contents of that log?

Comment: Where can I find the install log? (Windows 7)

Answer (score 0):

Try this link

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/572372/cuda-5-5-toolkit-install-fails-on-windows-7-possibly-solved-/

Alternatively, during installation, click custom installation, notice that some package are unavailable example "Cuda samples" etc, un-check those package that are not available.

Not sure why this answer insisted "must be at least 30 characters".